# Regarding symbol naming

Tags: discussion, naming

I have a question regarding a possible alternative name for a symbol and I'm not sure if this would be the correct place to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such questions are on-topic on the [main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/): see [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) and [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

When you ask the question,  remember to mention where you encountered the symbol, and include   some context (preferably more than one sentence).